# How should i integrate Azure Single Sign with multiple website in asp.net?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am new to Azure AD. I have to implement two websites which uses Azure Single Sign On feature to login. I have gone through few documents and blogs but it wasn't helpful enough. Could anyone suggest me a relevant document or approach for beginners.

This approach I am using:
I made a new tenant.
Made a app in app registration
Assigned the users through Enterprise Application changes

But now i have to add another website to webapp and then make sure if user logs in anyone of those then it should automatically get logged in other website as well.

Comment: what is the platform in which you have made the webapp? That web app needs to use any of the Microsoft Identity SDKs in order to support sign on with Azure AD accounts. For e.g if the webapp is Angular based, you can use `MSAL.js` to handle authentication using AAD.

Comment: The web app is made up of ASP.NET. I have integrated it will Azure AD but the issue is I have another website as well and I want to make sure it automatically log into that website as well when the security token is received by the user

Comment: That other web app need to register with AAD as well, in order to authenticate the user - the login flow will detect that user is already authenticated and will provide the token seamlessly. But webapp A cannot pass it's token to webapp B.

Answer (score 0):

***When you have multiple applications in your organization, it's better to use Azure AD and you are on the right path.***

> **To configure an application for SSO there are multiple ways. Based on your requirement you can choose any [**SSO protocol**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/plan-sso-deployment#single-sign-on-options) from below for authentication.**

There are protocols like **`OpenID Connect`**, **`OAuth`**, **`SAML`**, **`password-based`** etc. to configure SSO.

As you have two websites, register two webapps in Azure AD and [***configure SSO***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso#configure-single-sign-on-in-the-application)

While registering the webapps, make sure to add **redirect URI** or **Reply URLs** of those two websites respectively.

Make sure both webapps are using **same SSO protocol**.

As mentioned in the comment by [@Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran), while the user is authenticating, the login flow will detect that user is already authenticated and will provide the token seamlessly.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links to get some idea:

[Can I use Azure for SSO to multiple websites - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/770888/can-i-use-azure-for-sso-to-multiple-websites.html)

[single sign on - SSO with multiple azure web apps - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475444/sso-with-multiple-azure-web-apps)